# Chem-is-try is hard

Tags: mathematics, chemistry

You are a chemist and ask your coworker to puzzle you. They give you this puzzle and ask you to solve it.
`LiPSiNArHCaScMgHCaFPSiK`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The decrypted solution is:

> The word **Congratulations**.
>
>  Two-step decode:
>
>  First, convert chemical symbols to their atomic numbers.
>  Second, convert 1, 2, 3, ... to A, B, C, ...